# how to move the paragraph location to the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, database

Why I can't move the paragraph with the ID of "averageageatdeath" to the bottom of the table ? 
The paragraph is supposed to be at the bottom but something in the code is making it appear at the top.

here is the link of the whole code https://jsfiddle.net/lmanhaes/L5jwtzbf/2/

What is wrong in the $(document).ready(() => {}?
Do you guys think is the .text that is doing it?

```js
let dataTable = $("<table><thead><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Born</th><th>Died</th><th>Age of Death</th></tr></thead></table>");
$("body").append(dataTable.attr("class", "table")); // Create table skeleton and insert it into DOM. Add class for CSS styling 
$.each(data, (index, person) => {


    const dob = new Date(person.birthdate);
    const dod = new Date(person.deathdate);
    person.age = Math.floor((dod - dob) / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365.25));

    dataTable.append(
        "<tr><td>" + data[index].firstname +
        "</td><td>" + data[index].lastname +
        "</td><td>" + data[index].birthdate +
        "</td><td>" + data[index].deathdate +
        "</td><td>" + data[index].age
    );

});

$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#averageageatdeath').text("Average age at death = " + (data.reduce((total, person) =>
        total + person.age, 0) / data.length).toFixed(1));

});
```

Comment: See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/2xv56hgL/) I cleaned it up a bit and also moved the calculation in a separate function, as you wanted. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You are appending your data table to body, which means the table becomes the last element inside the body element.
It appears you intended for the `censusdata` div to be the container for your table, so if you change your line:
`$("body").append(dataTable.attr("class", "table"));`

to:
`$("#censusdata").append(dataTable.attr("class", "table"));`

Then it will work how you want.

Comment: If this answer helped, please be sure to [mark it as such](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)